# Special characters in the shell

Tags: linux, shell

I know that some characters like `"` or `*` need to be escaped to mean its literal value.

I wonder if is there any definitive set/list of all of them?

Comment: It depends on the shell you're using and sometimes even commands.

Comment: You can find a definitive description (though not a list) in the manpage of your shell, e.g. `man bash`.

Comment: duplicate: [Which characters need to be escaped in Bash? How do we know it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/995714), [List of special characters in the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93008/44425)

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have noted, it depends on the shell, as each is its own language.  For `bash` you can get a good list [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/SpecialCharacters)

The [POSIX shell syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) also includes a list, which is pretty similar to the one for `bash`.

Here's the POSIX list, though the `bash` link above also explains what is special about them:

```
|  &  ;  <  >  (  )  $  `  \  "  '  <space>  <tab>  <newline>
```

and

```
*   ?   [   #   ˜   =   %
```